# App crashes when setting wallpaper

Tags: android, crash, android-wallpaper

i'm trying to make an app that sets the user's wallpaper but it keeps crashing everytime I click the "Set Wallpaper" button.
I'm using 640X360px images that are 100-200kb each

My code is:

```
    package basics.noaml.com.basics;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.WallpaperManager;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;

/**
 * Created by Noam on 29/11/2014.
 */
public class TutorialThree extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener {

    ImageView display;
    int current;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.wallpaper);

        actions();
    }

    public void actions(){

        current = R.id.IVimage1;

        display = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.IVdisplay);
        ImageView image1 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.IVimage1);
        ImageView image2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.IVimage2);
        ImageView image3 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.IVimage3);
        ImageView image4 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.IVimage4);
        ImageView image5 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.IVimage5);
        ImageView image6 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.IVimage6);
        ImageView image7 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.IVimage7);
        Button setWall = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSetWallpaper);

        image1.setOnClickListener(this);
        image2.setOnClickListener(this);
        image3.setOnClickListener(this);
        image4.setOnClickListener(this);
        image5.setOnClickListener(this);
        image6.setOnClickListener(this);
        image7.setOnClickListener(this);
        setWall.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        switch (v.getId()){

            case R.id.IVimage1:
                display.setImageResource(R.drawable.bg_1);
                current = R.id.IVimage1;
                break;

            case R.id.IVimage2:
                display.setImageResource(R.drawable.bg_2);
                current = R.id.IVimage2;
                break;

            case R.id.IVimage3:
                display.setImageResource(R.drawable.bg_3);
                current = R.id.IVimage3;
                break;

            case R.id.IVimage4:
                display.setImageResource(R.drawable.bg_4);
                current = R.id.IVimage4;
                break;

            case R.id.IVimage5:
                display.setImageResource(R.drawable.bg_5);
                current = R.id.IVimage5;
                break;

            case R.id.IVimage6:
                display.setImageResource(R.drawable.bg_6);
                current = R.id.IVimage6;
                break;

            case R.id.IVimage7:
                display.setImageResource(R.drawable.bg_7);
                current = R.id.IVimage7;
                break;

            case R.id.bSetWallpaper:
                InputStream yeaaaa = getResources().openRawResource(current);
                Bitmap wallpaper = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(yeaaaa);

                WallpaperManager myWallpaperManager=WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());

                try {
                    myWallpaperManager.setBitmap(wallpaper);
                }
                catch (IOException e) {
                    Toast.makeText(TutorialThree.this, "Ooops, couldn't set the wallpaper", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

                break;

        }

    }
}
```

and the layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/IVdisplay"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="169dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:src="@drawable/bg_1" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bSetWallpaper"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:text="Set Image To Background" />


    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/IVimage1"
                android:layout_width="110dp"
                android:layout_height="66dp"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:src="@drawable/bg_1"/>

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/IVimage2"
                android:layout_width="110dp"
                android:layout_height="66dp"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:src="@drawable/bg_2" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/IVimage3"
                android:layout_width="110dp"
                android:layout_height="66dp"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:src="@drawable/bg_3" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/IVimage4"
                android:layout_width="110dp"
                android:layout_height="66dp"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:src="@drawable/bg_4" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/IVimage5"
                android:layout_width="110dp"
                android:layout_height="66dp"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:src="@drawable/bg_5" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/IVimage6"
                android:layout_width="110dp"
                android:layout_height="66dp"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:src="@drawable/bg_6" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/IVimage7"
                android:layout_width="110dp"
                android:layout_height="66dp"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:src="@drawable/bg_7" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </HorizontalScrollView>


</LinearLayout>
```

Logcat:

```
12-04 20:38:53.776  12776-12776/basics.noaml.com.basics V/Zygote﹕ Switching descriptor 59 to /dev/null
12-04 20:38:53.776  12776-12776/basics.noaml.com.basics V/Zygote﹕ Switching descriptor 10 to /dev/null
12-04 20:38:53.776  12776-12776/basics.noaml.com.basics D/dalvikvm﹕ Late-enabling CheckJNI
12-04 20:38:53.916  12776-12776/basics.noaml.com.basics D/ActivityThread﹕ handleBindApplication:basics.noaml.com.basics
12-04 20:38:53.916  12776-12776/basics.noaml.com.basics D/ActivityThread﹕ setTargetHeapUtilization:0.75
12-04 20:38:53.916  12776-12776/basics.noaml.com.basics D/ActivityThread﹕ setTargetHeapMinFree:524288
12-04 20:38:53.966  12776-12776/basics.noaml.com.basics I/dalvikvm﹕ DexOpt: illegal method access (call Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.<init> (Landroid/content/res/Resources;[I[II)V from Landroid/content/res/XResources$XTypedArray;)
12-04 20:38:53.966  12776-12776/basics.noaml.com.basics I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.<init>, referenced from method android.content.res.XResources$XTypedArray.<init>
12-04 20:38:53.966  12776-12776/basics.noaml.com.basics W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve direct method 82: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.<init> (Landroid/content/res/Resources;[I[II)V
12-04 20:38:53.966  12776-12776/basics.noaml.com.basics D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x70 at 0x0002
12-04 20:38:54.136  12776-12776/basics.noaml.com.basics E/MediaPlayer﹕ Should have subtitle controller already set
12-04 20:38:54.166  12776-12776/basics.noaml.com.basics I/Adreno-EGL﹕ <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:320>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM Build: I0404c4692afb8623f95c43aeb6d5e13ed4b30ddbDate: 11/06/13
12-04 20:38:54.186  12776-12776/basics.noaml.com.basics D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
12-04 20:38:54.206  12776-12776/basics.noaml.com.basics I/Xposed﹕ xxxxxx
12-04 20:38:54.266  12776-12776/basics.noaml.com.basics I/Timeline﹕ Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@41de9ea8 time:1381137
12-04 20:38:55.176  12776-12776/basics.noaml.com.basics D/dalvikvm﹕ JIT code cache reset in 0 ms (4096 bytes 4/0)
12-04 20:38:55.356  12776-12776/basics.noaml.com.basics I/Timeline﹕ Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@4259c638 time:1382223
12-04 20:38:57.166  12776-12776/basics.noaml.com.basics E/ActivityThread﹕ Performing stop of activity that is not resumed: {basics.noaml.com.basics/basics.noaml.com.basics.menu}
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Performing stop of activity that is not resumed: {basics.noaml.com.basics/basics.noaml.com.basics.menu}
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performStopActivityInner(ActivityThread.java:3164)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStopActivity(ActivityThread.java:3251)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:144)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1232)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5139)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:796)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:612)
            at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:132)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-04 20:39:28.176  12776-12776/basics.noaml.com.basics I/Timeline﹕ Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@4259c638 time:1415041
12-04 20:39:30.926  12776-12776/basics.noaml.com.basics I/Xposed﹕ xxxxxx
12-04 20:39:31.556  12776-12776/basics.noaml.com.basics I/Xposed﹕ xxxxxx
12-04 20:39:31.686  12776-12776/basics.noaml.com.basics E/MediaPlayer﹕ Should have subtitle controller already set
12-04 20:39:32.236  12776-12776/basics.noaml.com.basics I/Timeline﹕ Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@41dfc710 time:1419108
12-04 20:39:32.976  12776-12776/basics.noaml.com.basics I/Xposed﹕ xxxxxx
12-04 20:39:33.546  12776-12776/basics.noaml.com.basics I/Xposed﹕ xxxxxx
12-04 20:39:33.576  12776-12776/basics.noaml.com.basics D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
12-04 20:39:33.576  12776-12776/basics.noaml.com.basics W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x415fbce0)
12-04 20:39:33.586  12776-12776/basics.noaml.com.basics E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: basics.noaml.com.basics, PID: 12776
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.content.res.Resources.openRawResource(Resources.java:1085)
            at android.content.res.Resources.openRawResource(Resources.java:1056)
            at basics.noaml.com.basics.TutorialThree.onClick(TutorialThree.java:97)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4445)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18446)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5139)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:796)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:612)
            at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:132)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-04 20:39:35.626  12776-12776/basics.noaml.com.basics I/Process﹕ Sending signal. PID: 12776 SIG: 9
12-04 20:39:35.806  13778-13778/basics.noaml.com.basics D/ActivityThread﹕ handleBindApplication:basics.noaml.com.basics
12-04 20:39:35.806  13778-13778/basics.noaml.com.basics D/ActivityThread﹕ setTargetHeapUtilization:0.75
12-04 20:39:35.806  13778-13778/basics.noaml.com.basics D/ActivityThread﹕ setTargetHeapMinFree:524288
12-04 20:39:35.816  13778-13778/basics.noaml.com.basics I/dalvikvm﹕ DexOpt: illegal method access (call Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.<init> (Landroid/content/res/Resources;[I[II)V from Landroid/content/res/XResources$XTypedArray;)
12-04 20:39:35.816  13778-13778/basics.noaml.com.basics I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.<init>, referenced from method android.content.res.XResources$XTypedArray.<init>
12-04 20:39:35.816  13778-13778/basics.noaml.com.basics W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve direct method 82: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.<init> (Landroid/content/res/Resources;[I[II)V
12-04 20:39:35.816  13778-13778/basics.noaml.com.basics D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x70 at 0x0002
12-04 20:39:35.916  13778-13778/basics.noaml.com.basics I/Adreno-EGL﹕ <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:320>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM Build: I0404c4692afb8623f95c43aeb6d5e13ed4b30ddbDate: 11/06/13
12-04 20:39:35.926  13778-13778/basics.noaml.com.basics D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
12-04 20:39:35.976  13778-13778/basics.noaml.com.basics I/Timeline﹕ Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@41deb0e0 time:1422847
12-04 20:41:40.391  13778-13778/basics.noaml.com.basics I/Timeline﹕ Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@41deb0e0 time:1547235
12-04 20:41:41.551  13778-13778/basics.noaml.com.basics I/Xposed﹕ xxxxxx
12-04 20:41:41.691  13778-13778/basics.noaml.com.basics E/MediaPlayer﹕ Should have subtitle controller already set
12-04 20:41:41.761  13778-13778/basics.noaml.com.basics D/dalvikvm﹕ JIT code cache reset in 0 ms (4096 bytes 4/0)
12-04 20:41:41.771  13778-13789/basics.noaml.com.basics W/MediaPlayer-JNI﹕ MediaPlayer finalized without being released
12-04 20:41:42.361  13778-13778/basics.noaml.com.basics I/Timeline﹕ Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@42425358 time:1549209
12-04 20:41:43.001  13778-13778/basics.noaml.com.basics I/Xposed﹕ xxxxxx
12-04 20:41:43.471  13778-13778/basics.noaml.com.basics I/Xposed﹕ xxxxxx
12-04 20:41:43.711  13778-13778/basics.noaml.com.basics I/Xposed﹕ xxxxxx
12-04 20:41:44.641  13778-13778/basics.noaml.com.basics I/Xposed﹕ xxxxxx
12-04 20:41:45.091  13778-13778/basics.noaml.com.basics I/Xposed﹕ xxxxxx
12-04 20:41:45.181  13778-13778/basics.noaml.com.basics D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
12-04 20:41:45.191  13778-13778/basics.noaml.com.basics W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x415fbce0)
12-04 20:41:45.191  13778-13778/basics.noaml.com.basics E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: basics.noaml.com.basics, PID: 13778
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.content.res.Resources.openRawResource(Resources.java:1085)
            at android.content.res.Resources.openRawResource(Resources.java:1056)
            at basics.noaml.com.basics.TutorialThree.onClick(TutorialThree.java:97)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4445)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18446)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5139)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:796)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:612)
            at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:132)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-04 20:41:46.511  14049-14049/basics.noaml.com.basics D/ActivityThread﹕ handleBindApplication:basics.noaml.com.basics
12-04 20:41:46.511  14049-14049/basics.noaml.com.basics D/ActivityThread﹕ setTargetHeapUtilization:0.75
12-04 20:41:46.511  14049-14049/basics.noaml.com.basics D/ActivityThread﹕ setTargetHeapMinFree:524288
12-04 20:41:46.531  14049-14049/basics.noaml.com.basics I/dalvikvm﹕ DexOpt: illegal method access (call Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.<init> (Landroid/content/res/Resources;[I[II)V from Landroid/content/res/XResources$XTypedArray;)
12-04 20:41:46.531  14049-14049/basics.noaml.com.basics I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.<init>, referenced from method android.content.res.XResources$XTypedArray.<init>
12-04 20:41:46.531  14049-14049/basics.noaml.com.basics W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve direct method 82: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.<init> (Landroid/content/res/Resources;[I[II)V
12-04 20:41:46.531  14049-14049/basics.noaml.com.basics D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x70 at 0x0002
12-04 20:41:46.641  14049-14049/basics.noaml.com.basics I/Adreno-EGL﹕ <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:320>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM Build: I0404c4692afb8623f95c43aeb6d5e13ed4b30ddbDate: 11/06/13
12-04 20:41:46.661  14049-14049/basics.noaml.com.basics D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
12-04 20:41:46.711  14049-14049/basics.noaml.com.basics I/Timeline﹕ Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@41de76f8 time:1553553
12-04 20:41:53.021  14049-14049/basics.noaml.com.basics I/Timeline﹕ Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@41de76f8 time:1559863
12-04 21:15:03.174  18325-18325/basics.noaml.com.basics V/Zygote﹕ Switching descriptor 59 to /dev/null
12-04 21:15:03.174  18325-18325/basics.noaml.com.basics V/Zygote﹕ Switching descriptor 10 to /dev/null
12-04 21:15:03.184  18325-18325/basics.noaml.com.basics D/dalvikvm﹕ Late-enabling CheckJNI
12-04 21:15:03.304  18325-18325/basics.noaml.com.basics D/ActivityThread﹕ handleBindApplication:basics.noaml.com.basics
12-04 21:15:03.304  18325-18325/basics.noaml.com.basics D/ActivityThread﹕ setTargetHeapUtilization:0.75
12-04 21:15:03.304  18325-18325/basics.noaml.com.basics D/ActivityThread﹕ setTargetHeapMinFree:524288
12-04 21:15:03.324  18325-18325/basics.noaml.com.basics I/dalvikvm﹕ DexOpt: illegal method access (call Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.<init> (Landroid/content/res/Resources;[I[II)V from Landroid/content/res/XResources$XTypedArray;)
12-04 21:15:03.324  18325-18325/basics.noaml.com.basics I/dalvikvm﹕ Could not find method android.content.res.TypedArray.<init>, referenced from method android.content.res.XResources$XTypedArray.<init>
12-04 21:15:03.324  18325-18325/basics.noaml.com.basics W/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: unable to resolve direct method 82: Landroid/content/res/TypedArray;.<init> (Landroid/content/res/Resources;[I[II)V
12-04 21:15:03.324  18325-18325/basics.noaml.com.basics D/dalvikvm﹕ VFY: replacing opcode 0x70 at 0x0002
12-04 21:15:03.474  18325-18325/basics.noaml.com.basics E/MediaPlayer﹕ Should have subtitle controller already set
12-04 21:15:03.504  18325-18325/basics.noaml.com.basics I/Adreno-EGL﹕ <qeglDrvAPI_eglInitialize:320>: EGL 1.4 QUALCOMM Build: I0404c4692afb8623f95c43aeb6d5e13ed4b30ddbDate: 11/06/13
12-04 21:15:03.534  18325-18325/basics.noaml.com.basics D/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Enabling debug mode 0
12-04 21:15:03.604  18325-18325/basics.noaml.com.basics I/Timeline﹕ Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@41deaae0 time:2663065
12-04 21:15:04.534  18325-18325/basics.noaml.com.basics D/dalvikvm﹕ JIT code cache reset in 0 ms (4096 bytes 4/0)
12-04 21:15:04.714  18325-18325/basics.noaml.com.basics I/Timeline﹕ Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@4259b380 time:2664178
12-04 21:15:09.634  18325-18325/basics.noaml.com.basics I/Xposed﹕ xxxxxx
12-04 21:15:09.754  18325-18325/basics.noaml.com.basics E/MediaPlayer﹕ Should have subtitle controller already set
12-04 21:15:10.474  18325-18325/basics.noaml.com.basics I/Timeline﹕ Timeline: Activity_idle id: android.os.BinderProxy@41e5fe18 time:2669939
12-04 21:15:11.364  18325-18325/basics.noaml.com.basics I/Xposed﹕ xxxxxx
12-04 21:15:12.734  18325-18325/basics.noaml.com.basics I/Xposed﹕ xxxxxx
12-04 21:15:12.804  18325-18325/basics.noaml.com.basics D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
12-04 21:15:12.804  18325-18325/basics.noaml.com.basics W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x415fbce0)
12-04 21:15:12.804  18325-18325/basics.noaml.com.basics E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: basics.noaml.com.basics, PID: 18325
    java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.content.res.Resources.openRawResource(Resources.java:1085)
            at android.content.res.Resources.openRawResource(Resources.java:1056)
            at basics.noaml.com.basics.TutorialThree.onClick(TutorialThree.java:97)
            at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4445)
            at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18446)
            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5139)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:796)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:612)
            at de.robv.android.xposed.XposedBridge.main(XposedBridge.java:132)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are storing the id of the **imageView** in your **current** variable as:

```
current = R.id.IVimage1;
```

But you need to store the drawable id instead as:

```
current = R.drawable.bg_1;
```

That will fix it.

Don't forget that in the manifest you need to add the following permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

`getResources()` is part of `Context`. You can use it like that in an `Activity` because it inherits from `Context`. You need to pass in your activity's Context to use `getResources`.

Comment: And what does it mean? this is kinda new for me

Comment: A Context is a handle to the system; it provides services like resolving resources, obtaining access to databases and preferences, and so on. It is an "interface" that allows access to application specific resources and class and information about application environment. Your activities and services also extend Context to they inherit all those methods to access the environment information in which the application is running.